# Uninstallation and installation of a component require two reboots

Tags: windows-installer

I have a tool which updates the set of component by uninstalling old and installs latest.
If a component(MSI) requires reboot on installation and uninstallation, Is it really requires two reboots for to update the component?

The tool actually reduces the number of reboots by installing multiple components at once, even if multiple components had reboot after installation it will continue installation of all components which don't have dependency on other components.
Suppose A,B,C components requires reboot after installation, and C has a dependency on A then it first installs A and B then after reboot it installs C.
Now if we come to uninstallation does installation of 'A' have dependency on uninstallation of 'A'?

Comment: You should clarify the question. Windows Installer components aren't installed without a containing package, an MSI file or patch, and they are upgraded using major upgrade, patch, minor upgrade etc. You might have a tool that does an update by uninstalling one product and then installing the new one, but that's only a guess.

Comment: Yes, Tool uninstalls older version and installs new one

Answer (score 0):

Do the uninstall with an MSI log, and see what's going on. The command line needs /l*vx [path to log file] adding.

Typically the issue is files in use (that can't be deleted during the uninstall) because, (for example) services haven't been stopped or other processes are still running. If that's the case the log will have some 1603 messages. When you identify the processes or services it's a matter of shutting them down, but since you don't say what tool you're using to build the MSIs it's not possible to suggest a solution.